# How are composition algebras useful?

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory, soft-question

I know that algebras over fields are useful. However, I am at a loss to see why composition algebras and the seemingly arbitrary definition of quadratic forms are useful. How are composition algebras useful in areas other than abstract algebra?

Comment: Why does the definition of a quadratic form seem *arbitrary*? Maybe you are seeing an abstract definition? Concretely, quadratic forms are homogeneous polynomials of degree 2 and the case of two variables over the reals is closely connected to geometry (level sets of a quadratic form can be ellipses or hyperbolas) and over the integers is closely connected to number theory (Pell’s equation for $x^2-dy^2$, Gaussian integers for $x^2+y^2$).

Comment: I felt that the part about being bilinear was arbitrary.

Comment: Ah, so you are looking at the coordinate-free definition of quadratic forms. If you pick a basis, that abstractly defined function $Q:V \to k$ is just a homogeneous quadratic polynomial in the coordinates of vectors in $V$. I agree that the basis-free definition seems peculiar when you first meet it.

Comment: I think the discussion on the MO page https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430365 about the possibility of generalizing the theory of quadratic forms to higher degree will interest you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does number theory count as a field other than abstract algebra? Quadratic forms seem like a very natural thing to consider from the point of view of number theory. If your quadratic form comes from a composition algebra, this gives you more tools to work with.

Quaternion algebras come up naturally in number-theoretic contexts such as automorphic forms or even just algebraic groups. The unit group of a non-split quaternion algebra are the non-split forms of the algebraic group $\mathrm{GL}_2$.

Octonion algebras appear when you want to describe the exceptional algebraic groups over a field, especially those with Dynkin diagram $G_2$.

In topology, quaternions and octonions give rise to certain fiber sequences which relate various homotopy groups of spheres. The famous Hopf fibration may be described via quaternions.